# Retrieve the headers in excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

[image: Please click here to view the Excel file]

I want to retrieve headers of this excel file (Only A,B,C)and store it in a list using Python. I opened my file but I am unable to retrieve it.

```
import xlrd
file_location= "C:/Users/Desktop/Book1.xlsx"
workbook= xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Can anyone please help me with that? I am new to Python.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you open to use pandas library and maybe read the whole excel file easily ?

Comment: I can use anything but I don't want the rest of the data. Only headers

Comment: which row is the headers, I see two rows which could be them.

Comment: Updated the post. Only A,B, C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using the numpy method loadtxt:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html
Which gives you arrays for each column (you can also skip specified columns so that you only get the A,B,C as you desire). You can write a for loop to get the first entry of each column and put them in a list.

```
data = loadtxt("Book1.xlsx")
headers = [] 
for c in range(1,data.shape[0]): 
    if data[c, 0] != "": 
        headers.append(data[c, 0])
```

Comment: Hi, but I might add a couple of columns in future so I can't hard code the number. Can you syntactically tell me how do I do that?

Comment: You can do:
`data = loadtxt("Book1.xlsx")`

`headers = [data[c,0] for c in range(data.shape[0] if data[c,0] != ""]`

Comment: You can also skip the first column by changing the range arguments to `range(1,data.shape[0])`

Comment: I am getting following error:>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> headers = [data[c,0] for c in range(1,data.shape[0]) if data[c,0] != ""]
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Did you install and import numpy? I just tried on my machine, worked fine.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure the generator expression is smooth, so try this:
`headers = []`
`for c in range(1,data.shape[0]):`
     `if data[c, 0] != "":`
         `headers.append(data[c, 0])`

Comment: @CaryShindell can you update your answer with the example code you commented?

Answer (score 1):

```
iterheaders = iter(sheet.row(1))
headers = [str(cell.value) for cell in iterheaders[1:] if cell is not None and cell.value != '']
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Hi, Thanks! This helped partially but the output is ['Date', '', 'A', '', '', 'B', '', '', 'C', '']
I want it look as [A, B, C]. Thanks.

Comment: Then try to do this instead:
`headers = [str(cell.value) for cell in iterheaders if cell is not None and cell != '']`

Comment: Sorry that didn't work either! Still the same output

Comment: Try now @Programmer?

Comment: so, you accepted the answer without understanding it? Great...

The update skips the first column and adds the check that @AndreasLympouras suggested in his comment